# error group_by laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo una vista en la cual necesito dibujar un grafico de tortam  la siguiente consulta en mysql que tiene como objetivo obtener el total de registros y sus estados (el estado es un campo numérico) y con el if lo que busco es enviar a la vista un texto en lugar del valor numérico:

```
SELECT id, count(*), if(status = 0, "Activo", "Finalizado")as estado FROM `mantenimientos` GROUP BY(status)
```

como se ve me trae la data:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que al tratar de usar esa query en el controlador me da error en el GROUP BY... En el controlador tengo la query asi:

```
        $serviciosestado = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id, count(status), if(status = 0, 'Activo', 'Finalizado')as estado FROM mantenimientos GROUP BY(estado)"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer un "group by" los otros campos deben tener una operación agrupadora (como el mismo count(*), o un Sum(), etc ) para funcionar.